# Spinner selections made in RecyclerView are getting reset when scrolled out of view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences, android-spinner

In Android, what are some ways to prevent `Spinners` in a `RecyclerView` from getting reset when the spinners move out of view? They all have same `Id`, so it's not possible to save the selections in the `ShardPreferences` object. And I don't think saving the state of the entire activity is applicable here either.

Comment: You think wrong. You must save the selected index of every spinner preferably in your adapter and restore it in onBindViewHolder

Comment: How do I save / restore every spinner? Remember, I have multiple spinners. Does each spinner have a unique ID?

Comment: You can find examples in SO about listeners for spinners and how to save the selected values in an ArrayList

Comment: I have been searching for a few hours. Do you have a solid example?

Comment: An example to suit exactly your needs, no I haven't, because I did not search.

Comment: @b1gtuna check my example it match your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this workaround 
create a `HashMap` inside your `adapter` of the positions of your items and the value will be the selected index in spinner 
or you can add an attribute to your model called `spinnerIndex` to save the index in your item 
all your work will be inside the `onBindViewHolder`
example

```
public class Item {

    int spinnerSelectedIndex;

    public int getSpinnerSelectedIndex() {
        return spinnerSelectedIndex;
    }

    public void setSpinnerSelectedIndex(int spinnerSelectedIndex) {
        this.spinnerSelectedIndex = spinnerSelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

inside your `onBindViewHolder`

```
spinnerObject.setSelection(getSpinnerSelectedIndex());
```

and you get your index filled from `onItemSelected` callback 
like this when sett the listener for spinner

```
spinnerObject.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
                item. setSpinnerSelectedIndex(arg2)
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks this looks promising. Unfortunately setting one spinner seems to set the selections for other spinners. Can your method handle multiple spinners of the same type (~10)?

Comment: you should set the selection for the spinner inside the onBindViewHolder method 
this will make every spinner has its own selection spinnerObject.setSelection(item.getSpinnerSelectedIndex());
since each item has a different value

Comment: This is what I am doing inside onBindViewHolder in my Adapter -   holder.encodedLetter.setSelection(item.getSpinnerSelectedIndex());

Comment: are you setting a new  adapter to each spinner?  encodedLetter.setadapter ? or to all ? 
if not you need to create a new  adapter inside the bindviewholder and attach it to the spinner before setselection

Comment: I was creating (with the "new" keyword) an adapter in the constructor of my adapter, not in onBindViewHolder. So now in "onBindViewHolder", 1) I am creating a new adapter 2) holder.encodedLetter.setAdapter(newAdapter) 3) holder.encodedLetter.setSelection(item.getSpinnerSelectedIndex()); Unfortunately I am still seeing the issue!

Answer (score 0):

If your list is a read only and list items don't change, then you can use viewholder.setIsRecyclable(false).

I am still looking for a way though when you have list items of whose change.